# fatal error: libudev.h: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

I compile with g++/gcc on ubuntu12.04 and it is "OK" but I cannot cross compile using raspberry pi tools master

```
toolsmaster 
CC := /home/Desktop/Simple_Linux_Driver/tools-master/arm-bcm2708/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi-g++
GCC := /home/Desktop/Simple_Linux_Driver/tools-master/arm-bcm2708/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi-gcc
```

I had install the following item:

```
-sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev
-sudo apt-get install libudev-dev
```

raspberry pi kernel version 3.2.27 (izzit I need to enable "how" and rebuilt again)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its works!!! i need to cross compile and cp .h .so inside raspberry pi cross toolsmaster
Below is what i try:
Do let me know if i miss out anythings Thanks^^
download libusb latest version tar file.

version 1.0.8

```
$ TOOLCHAIN=/opt/FriendlyArm/toolchain/4.4.3/arm-none-linux-gnueabi
$ PATH=$PATH:$TOOLCHAIN/bin
$ CC='arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -march=armv4t -mtune=arm920t'
$ CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-
$ export CC CROSS_COMPILE
$ tar xfv libusb-1.0.8.tar
$ cd libusb-1.0.8
$ ./configure --host arm-linux
$ make
$ cd libusb
$ cp libusb.h $TOOLCHAIN/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/include/
$ cp libusb.h $TOOLCHAIN/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/include/
$ cp .libs/libusb-1.0.so $TOOLCHAIN/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/lib/
$ cp .libs/libusb-1.0.so $TOOLCHAIN/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/
```

THE TOOLCHAIN IS SET.
for writing programs:
add #include to use he library.
compile using following:

```
$arm-linux-g++ myprog.cpp -o myapp -lusb-1.0
```

NOTE: DON'T MISSOUT ON "-lusb-1.0"

Answer (score 0):

If you do above it will install libraries that is for x86.
The above libraries should be in raspberry cross-tool chain. if its not present then you need cross-compile it for arm architecture. Then you have to export it by follwing cmd

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path to library`

First export the tools using `export` command.

`export PATH=$PATH:/path to tool chain`

Before doing above 1st try the following

e.g export PATH=$PATH:/home/Desktop/Simple_Linux_Driver/tools-master/arm-bcm2708/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi/bin/

if you want to export it everytime in every terminal then .

`vi .bashrc`

At the end of file just add below command .

`export PATH=/path to tool chain bin:$PATH`

e.g `export PATH=/opt/Arm_tool_chain/bin:$PATH`

Comment: first what you are trying to compile.2)where you are compiling in x86 or raspberry board?

Comment: i am trying to compile a USB driver code i get from github (https://github.com/signal11/hidapi). i using x86 to compile the code.

Comment: Can you share your Makefile. so that i can figure out what exactly you trying

Comment: can i send through your email? i had try cross compile with libusb using raspberry pi toolmaster and it is works but i not yet try on the libudev yet.

Comment: Ok  send me with little bit explanation what you trying to do.In above comment its not clear what you are saying . here is my id vinayhunachyal@gmail.com